# If the express server runs with scripts in package.json it won't come up

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

Everything is working web server.
But when I run certain commands with script in package.json, I get a 404 error.

Below is the ecosystem.config.js file configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'test',
    script: './bin/www',
    instances: 1,
    exec_mode : "cluster",
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    args: ["master"],
    log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    script: './bin/www',
    instances: 7,
    exec_mode : "cluster",
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    args: ["slave"],
    log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
  }]
};
```

Below is the script in package.json that I tested.

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ecosystem.config.js" // success
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 delete test & pm2 start ecosystem.config.js" // fail
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 delete test && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js" // fail
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www" // success
```

"test" is the value of the name property of ecosystem.config.js.
Run "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js" and it should work.
However, using "pm2 delete test" command together causes 404 error on the web server.
The command "pm2 delete test" runs normally. I actually saw "test" processes run again after they disappeared.
I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: You can do one thing I don't know it's right or wrong but keep the pm2 script separate in one script and the cross-env set up in the second script make a third script which runs these two using the &&. I hope this helps

Comment: @yashvadhvani 
lol... as you said, setting the cross-env in front of the command afterwards works really well. Thank you so much for solving my concerns.

Comment: @yashvadhvani 
of course. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing I don't know it's right or wrong but keep the pm2 script separate in one script and the cross-env set up in the second script make a third script which runs these two.

Example..

```
test1: "cross-env NODE_ENV=production",
test2: "pm2 delete test && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
test3: "npm run test1 && npm run test2"
```